# Why doesn't the "Yes" method run?

Tags: c#

I have this code that should take the variable `usersResp`, see if it matches an element from the `yes` array (that is in the `Yes` method) and print out the variable `Case`. Depending on the match, it should either be `0` if none matched (there were no elements in the array that were the same as `usersResp`) or `1` if an element matched.

Here's the code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   string usersResp = "y";
   int Case = 0;
   Yes(usersResp, Case);
   Console.WriteLine(Case);
}

static void Yes(string UserResponse, int Case)
{
    string[] yes = new string[] { "y", "Y", "Yes", "yes", "yup", "Yup", "ok", "Ok", "Alright", "alright", "yeah", "Yeah", "Sure", "sure", "of course", "Of course", "k", "K" };

    for (int i = 0; i < yes.Length; i++)
    {
        if (UserResponse == yes[i])
        {
            Case = 1;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I can't figure out why it runs incorrectly and the `Case` always stays 0. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: side note : While this is valid C# code, having a function named `Yes` and a variable named `yes` may lead to confusion. Also, why returning 0 or 1 ? won't you prefer return a boolean ?

Comment: Your code modifies a *copy* of `Case`, not the original variable. Using such code is a bad idea anyway. It;s better to return the new value instead of trying to modify the variable

Comment: Are you sure you aren't looking for the `Contains` method? The `Yes` function could be replaced with a single method call to eg `HashSet.Contains` or even [Enumerable.Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=net-5.0) with a case-insensitive comparer

Comment: @SteveB I need to return 1 as there are also other cases

Comment: @CamilaA. what other cases? You can return whatever you want based on the return value of `Contains` eg `yesArray.Contains(userResp,StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)?1:0` or. `yesSet.Contains(userResp)?1:0`. There's no need for such a loop

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for the suggestion. I'm still new to programming and haven't gotten to learn many methods yet, so I didn't know about that one).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disregarding any other issue conceptual or otherwise.

You will need to pass `int case` by *reference*, not *value*

```
static void Yes(string UserResponse, ref int Case)
```

---

**Additional Resources**

[Passing an argument by reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref#passing-an-argument-by-reference)

> When used in a method's parameter list, the ref keyword indicates that
> an argument is passed by reference, not by value. The ref keyword
> makes the formal parameter an alias for the argument, which must be a
> variable. In other words, any operation on the parameter is made on
> the argument.

Another way you could do this, is use a `HashSet` with a *string comparer*. This will give you a nice fast lookup by just using `Contains`. In the following example I use `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` Which will in turn be case insensitive

```
public static HashSet<string>  YesHashSet = new(
   new[] { "y", "yes", "yup", "ok", "alright", "Yeah", "sure", "of course", "K" },
   StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
...

public static bool IsYes(string userResponse)
   => YesHashSet.Contains(userResponse);
```

---

**More Resources**

[`HashSet<T>` Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-5.0)

> Represents a set of values.

[`HashSet<T>(IEnumerable<T>, IEqualityComparer<T>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_HashSet_1__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable__0__System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer__0__)

> Initializes a new instance of the HashSet class that uses the
> specified equality comparer for the set type, contains elements copied
> from the specified collection, and has sufficient capacity to
> accommodate the number of elements copied.

[`StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase Property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer.invariantcultureignorecase?view=net-5.0)

> Gets a StringComparer object that performs a case-insensitive string
> comparison using the word comparison rules of the invariant culture.

Comment: I don't think there is any need to use `ref` for this. While it will work, seems like overkill.

Comment: It would be far better to return the new value than modify the variable through side-effects

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks, I'll try it that way, too

Comment: YesHashSet should be `private readonly static` I guess

Answer (score 6):

I would handle it like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   string usersResp = "y";
   int Case = Yes(usersResp);
   Console.WriteLine(Case);
}
static int Yes(string UserResponse)
{
   string[] yes = new string[] { "y", "Y", "Yes", "yes", "yup", "Yup", "ok", "Ok", "Alright", "alright", "yeah", "Yeah", "Sure", "sure", "of course", "Of course", "k", "K" };

    for (int i = 0; i < yes.Length; i++)
    {
        if (UserResponse == yes[i])
        {
            return 1;
        }
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: change return type to int :)

Comment: You *really* would write it that way? Why? Case insensitive `HashSet` is guaranteed to work and leads to shorter code...

Comment: I meant the part of getting the value. The function itself, the magic strings and so forth would not be like that.

Comment: `String.Equals` also allows for case-insensitive comparisons through the `StringComparison` parameter

Comment: This code wouldn't work for me because the variable `Case` doesn't just change from the method `Yes`. There are also other methods that can change it's value if it meets their conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Use out modifier

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   string usersResp = "y";
   int Case = 0;
   Yes(usersResp,out Case);
   Console.WriteLine(Case);
}
static void Yes(string UserResponse,out int Case)
    {
   string[] yes = new string[] { "y", "Y", "Yes", "yes", "yup", "Yup", "ok", "Ok", "Alright", "alright", "yeah", "Yeah", "Sure", "sure", "of course", "Of course", "k", "K" };

            for (int i = 0; i < yes.Length; i++)
            {
                if (UserResponse == yes[i])
                {
                    Case = 1;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why doesn't the “Yes” method run?

It is actually running. Put a `Console.WriteLine("Hello");` inside it, and you'll find the `Hello` printed on the console. So, rest assured, the `Yes` method is running.

> why it runs incorrectly and the Case always stays 0

It is not running incorrectly. In fact, everything is running exactly as the are supposed to. You are not getting the expected result because of the following three facts combined -

1. You are changing the value of `Case` inside the `Yes` method
2. You are printing the value of `Case` from the `Main` method
3. The `Case` in the `Main` method and `Case` passed to the `Yes` method are not the same. So any changes made to the `Case` inside the `Yes` method, will not change the `Case` in the `Main` method.

That is why, even though you are changing the value of `Case` inside the `Yes` method, the `Main` method is still printing the value it previously had for the `Case` variable.

To get your expected result, you have to notify the `Main` method about the change you have made inside the `Yes` method. You can do that by -

1. Returning the modified value of `Case` explicitly from the `Yes` method with the `return` keyword, as @Athanasios has shown in his answer.
2. Returning the modified value of `Case` implicitly from the `Yes` method by passing the `Case` as a `ref` or `out` parameter, as @00110001 and @NCCSBIM071 have shown in their answers.

Comment: The function code itself does not return anything. This change would not even compile.

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras Modified the answer.